# Change debounce time of keyboard

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, windows-registry

I have an HP Elitebook 8570W laptop.

I get lots and lots of typos because the keyboard "thinks" I accidentally hit two keys. nonononono! I just type very fast.

Is there any way to change the debounce time of this keyboard?

Comment: Those settings are generally related to OS, so please post your operating system too. Also, what are the typos, why do you think you type too fast?

Comment: @MátéJuhász, the typos are any double key such as "aa", "oo" etcetera and any two keys hit in rapid sucession (using ten fingers). And I don't _think_ I type too fast, I know it. Ever used a real IBM101 keyboard? That lets you type really fast!

Comment: are you talking about double clicks? I have noticed double clicks that i don't make, and i hope your answer will help.

Comment: @AlexanderMyravjev, I believe the hardware/software considers any two keystrokes that fall within the bounce time as a typing error and only considers the first keystroke, ignoring the second. Formally, though, the debounce time has to do that an electrical/mechanical contact can have "sparks" when pressed that would be seen as multiple keystrokes but that should be ignored.

Answer (score 5):

I found an article on [hp](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/Keyboard-has-a-tendency-to-repeat-keystrokes-maaking/td-p/2650729) which says to decrease the keyboard debounce time in the registry, however on my Windows 7 this time was zero. Maybe this zero says "use default" or maybe this zero means the debounce is done by the hardware.

Anyway, I changed it to 35 ms and later to 20 ms and it seems to have worked as I have much less typos than before. The registry key is:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Accessibility\Keyboard Response\BounceTime
```